# Animate elements every time when in viewport

Tags: wordpress, css, animation, bounce

I made animation on contact form on my WordPress site. Animation(bounce) is triggered when i scroll page to contact form... But now i need some modification : I need animation to repeat every time when scroll to contact form .
Can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

I would use a plugin like animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Just include the stylesheet and add the class `bounce` to the element you want the affect to appear on i.e your form.

Comment: Yes ..Idea with plugin is great, I use AnimateIt!
But now i have a different problem...I changed my question above so please try help.